# how to transfer contents from 1d array to a 2d array in a specific form in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

the result must look like

```
// Eg1: 1d array 
b[]={1,2,3}

// 2d array 
// 1 0 3
// 0 2 0
// 1 0 3 

//Eg2: 1d array 
b[]={1,2,3,4}

// 2d array  
// 1 0 0 4 
// 0 2 3 0 
// 0 2 3 0 
// 1 0 0 4
```

Comment: Please show us what youve tried

Comment: sir i am a newbie so i could not do much i just know that we need to run 2 loops and i have done a few simpler combinations of transferring from 1d array to 2d array

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Go ahead and implement those loops, when you run into an error, you'll have a more specific question to ask.

Comment: Think about it this way: given a position (x, y) in the 2D array, what number should go there? Write out a flowchart for how to decide. (e.g. is it in a corner? on an edge? etc.)

Comment: i am sry but i could not post the code it says some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// a[] is 1d array contain input, b[][] is 2d array that will contain result, n is size of the array

//set all b[][] content to 0 first
for (int i = 0; i < n;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) b[i][j] = 0;
}

//this is the process to move content from a[] to b[][]
for (int i = 0; i < n ;i++)
{
    b[i][i] = a[i];
    b[n-i-1][i] = a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lets call the array **A**, **n** the size of **A** and the matrix **M** (**n** x **n**)

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        M[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    M[i][i] = M[n-i-1][i] = A[i];
}
```

something like this should work

Answer (score -1):

At runtime there is no such thing as a 2D array in C++, at least not in the absence of an ADT.  A 2D array only exists at compile time, at runtime you must address the array linearly, mapping indices yourself.

Comment: I disagree with the statement "There is no such thing as a 2D array in C++". There is syntax for 2D / arrays of arrays, and they are widely used and referred to as such. The compiler handles the 2D->linear index mapping for you; the _computer_ must access memory linearly, but _you_ (the programmer) don't. Besides, this doesn't even attempt at being an answer to the OP's question (regardless of the question's quality).

Comment: I don't see a 2D array into which I can map anything.  I concluded that since he was confused at the matter he received a pointer to an array which is dynamically allocated, and was not allowed to use static allocation semantics, I don't think that's an unfair assessment.  I just did my best to answer given the quality of the question.